# Problem with a reusable python function to retrieve data from sqlite table

Tags: python, function, sqlite

Hello and good day to you guys wherever you are now. I have a problem about a python reusable function to retrieve data from an sqlite database. By reusable I mean a function I can plug in whatever piece of code that needs it. If you have the proper name don't hesitate to educate me, I am willing to learn from you.
Anyway below is the code.

```
def retrieve_data(self, table_name, columns="*", condition=""):
    try:
        # Construct the SELECT query
        select_query = f"SELECT {columns} FROM {table_name} {condition};"

        # Execute the select query
        cursor.execute(select_query)

        # Fetch all rows
        result = cursor.fetchall()

        return result

    except sqlite3.Error as e:
        print(f"Error retrieving data: {e}")
        return None
```

Now the issue is initially when I called the above function in my code it take the value gotten from a wxpython text widget as the column instead of the value in that column, thereby throwing the column not existing error. For example the column name is column_name and the value entered by the user from the text widget is value_in_column, it takes the value_in_column as column_name. So, it throw this error Error retrieving data: no such column: the_text_gotten from the wxpython tet entry widget.

Check below for the code I used to call the reusable function.

```
def add_subject(self, event):
    if self.subject_name_text.GetValue()!="":
        get_subject_list = SchoolManagementSystem.retrieve_data(SchoolManagementSystem, "subject", "subject_name", f"where subject_name = {self.subject_name_text.GetValue()}")

        subject_list = list(get_subject_list)
        if self.subject_name_text.GetValue() in subject_list:
            print(f"Class {self.subject_name_text.GetValue()} already exists.")
        else:
            subject_list.append(self.subject_name_text.GetValue())
            print(f"Subject {self.subject_name_text.GetValue()}")
            print(subject_list)
        SchoolManagementSystem.insert_row(SchoolManagementSystem, "subject", {"subject_name":self.subject_name_text.GetValue()})
```

I have tried tinkering with the strings in the condition argument as I suspect there lies the source of my headache but I wasn't successful. Hence, I bring it here for the expert to help me out. I anticipate your helpful response. Thanks.

Comment: All functions are potentially reusable, that's the point of defining them.

Comment: Your attempt is simultaneously too smart and too dumb at the same time. `f"SELECT {columns} FROM {table_name} {condition};"` is nightmare fuel when your function doesn't even try to account for parameterisation. You can't realistically boil what you're trying to do down to a single "do-all" function here. Look up SQL Injection

Answer (score 3):

As suggested earlier it might be helpful to change conception a little bit. You can try to make more specific functions like:

```
def get_subject_by_name(self, subject_name: str):
    query = "SELECT col1 as col_alias1, col2 as col_alias2 FROM subject_table where subject_name = ?"
    cursor.execute(query, (subject_name, ))
    ...
```

and then:

```
SchoolManagmentSystem.get_subject_by_name(name_to_find)
```

Inserting user provided inputs directly into the query is not recommended because of potential for SQL injection attacks: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

You might also think about using SqlAlchemy with it's ORM depending on usecase:
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the entered value in quotes.

```
f"where subject_name = '{self.subject_name_text.GetValue()}'"
```

However, it's not a good idea to substitute values directly into the query string like this (it won't work if the value contains quotes, for instance), you should use a query with placeholders and a separate parameter list. See [How to use variables in SQL statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python)

```
def retrieve_data(self, table_name, columns="*", condition="", values=()):
    try:
        # Construct the SELECT query
        select_query = f"SELECT {columns} FROM {table_name} {condition};"

        # Execute the select query
        cursor.execute(select_query, values)

        # Fetch all rows
        result = cursor.fetchall()

        return result

    except sqlite3.Error as e:
        print(f"Error retrieving data: {e}")
        return None
```

Then you call it like this:

```
get_subject_list = SchoolManagementSystem.retrieve_data(SchoolManagementSystem, "subject", "subject_name", "where subject_name = ?", (self.subject_name_text.GetValue(),))
```

Comment: `f"where subject_name = ?"` wut?

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Why have you made that an f-string?

Comment: I just didn't *un*-make it when I copied the original code....

Comment: Mmm. I'm not sure that this answer really helps move things forward for the OP. Whether or not this code actually works, I'm not sure at first glance, but I wouldn't want to be using it myself and I don't think it's teaching anyone good practice. If you don't correct carry-over redundancy like the f-string, I wonder how much thought you've put into this

Comment: It's pretty simple stuff, what *real* problems do you see with it? I explained why he got an error in his original code, and showed a much better way to do it that avoids the problem.

Comment: Thanks so much at Barmar. Your explanation was very clear, I will do as you instructed above. Needless to say while tinkering with the strings in the condition parameter I typed the first code you posted in your answer where you embed single quote within the double quote, just around the self.subject_name_text.GetValue() but it did not work then. Let me try it again and let you know.

Comment: Please don't waste your time trying to get that to work. Use the version with parameters.

Comment: I find `retrieve_data` to be too much. Making it work in this case is one thing but I would reject it in code review. I can't call it a "god object" but this is too much. If this is your general practice then fine, but it's not mine. To me, the connection object should be passed around to each function

Comment: I'm not a professional Python programmer, I just play one on SO, so I don't have a "general practice". But use of placeholders in queries is recommended practice. Lots of people like to write generic query procedures like this, I agree with you that they're not really necessary, but to each his own.

Comment: I'm not going to try to impress my opinion about this coding style. But if you're going to write such a procedure, you should do it correctly, that's what my answer tries to show.

Comment: I tried the correct version you posted and it is throwing up  the following error: Error retrieving data: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 0 supplied. I even tried it without the f-string still the same.

Comment: Sounds like you forgot the argument `(self.subject_name_text.GetValue(),)` when calling the function, so it used the default.

Comment: No, I didn't. Here is the code ```get_subject_list = SchoolManagementSystem.retrieve_data(SchoolManagementSystem, "subject", "subject_name", f"where subject_name =?", (self.subject_name_text.GetValue(),))```

Comment: I Just tested my code and it works. I simplified it to an ordinary function rather than a method since I don't have your class structure, but that shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: BTW, since the method doesn't use any instance variables, it should be a `@staticmethod`. Then you can get rid of the unused first argument.

Comment: roganjosh I don't know much about sql injection I am glad you mentioned that I have a looked at it and it is after that I get the point you made. Which simply means in my case I shouldn't pass the values directly through the function argument as that will give user with malicious intent a way of "injecting" their own values thereby manipulating the sql. I will make sure I take that into account as it will benefit me immensely.

Comment: By unused first argument do you mean the first argument in retrieve_data? ```SchoolManagementSystem```?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. The function never uses `self`.